# how to get complete table in which elements are appended dynamically from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table in my html page as given below-

```
 <table style='color:darkblue;' height = '219' class='table-main' id='packageList2' border = '1' bordercolor = '#ccc' cellpadding = '0' cellspacing = '0' >
                                <th>Services</th>
                                <th>Frequency</th>
                                <th>Silver</th>
                                <th>Gold</th>
                                <th>Platinum</th>
                            </table>
```

all other  and  elements are appended on this table through jquery dynamically by using JSON data.  now after this when I am getting this table in a variable as html in jquery by using-

```
var table= $('#packageList2').html();
```

I get only  and  part not the appended data.
 Please help me how to get complete table as html including the appended data.

Comment: You need to show us more of your code; include the part that loads the JSON data, appends the new data to the table, and then gets the HTML for the table. From the brief description you've given, I'd guess that you're using AJAX and are confused about exactly how asynchronous functions work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#packageList2').prop('outerHTML')
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/cg6q8pgp/

Answer (score 0):

May be the jquery framework has the cached about the table. So you must use the document.getElementById to get the element, then use the $() wrap the result.

code just like:
`$(document.getElementById('packageList2')).html()`